# SQL: Using an alias in order case statement

Tags: sql-server-2008, alias

I have a (sql server 2008) query as follows:

```
 Select *, column1+column2 as alias1
 From complaints
 Order by 
 Case 
   When @param1 = 'filedate' then filedate
   When @param1 = 'calc' then alias1
 End
```

This doesn't work, because ordering on an alias in a case statement is not allowed, it doesn't recognize alias1.

Is there another way this can be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

either put it in a CTE and then order by...

```
; with cteQuery as (Select *, column1+column2 as alias1 from complaints)
SELECT * from cteQuery Order by 
Case 
   When @param1 = 'filedate' then filedate
   When @param1 = 'calc' then alias1
 End
```

or just duplicate what the alias actually refers to...

```
Select *, column1+column2 as alias1
 From complaints
 Order by 
 Case 
   When @param1 = 'filedate' then filedate
   When @param1 = 'calc' then column1+column2
 End
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks, I like the CTE approch. I will try it!

Answer (score 3):

Simplest answer:

```
 Select complaints.*, column1+column2 as alias1
 From complaints
 Order by 
 Case 
   When @param1 = 'filedate' then filedate
   When @param1 = 'calc' then column1+column2
 End
```

Comment: Thanks! In my case the expression is complex, so maybe this has performance impact? I also don't like the duplication...

Comment: I don't know about performance, although normally disk access is a much bigger factor than calculations in query performance. The sub-query approach in Stuart's second query and Andrew's first (CTE-based) query neatly remove the duplication.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select *, column1+column2 as alias1  
From complaints  
Order by   Case
     When @param1 = 'filedate' then filedate
    When @param1 = 'calc' then column1+column2
  End
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM (    Select *, column1+column2 as alias1  
    From complaints ) c 
    Order by   Case
         When @param1 = 'filedate' then filedate
        When @param1 = 'calc' then alias1
      End
```

Comment: Thank you! In my actual case, it's a complex formula with geo locations. Is the first solution going to be a performance issue? It seems the second solution may solve my issue! I'll try this and let you know.